# Puppet Agent will not run a PowerShell script on its own

Tags: powershell, puppet

I'm at a loss, I don't know what else to look at on this for getting my Puppet manifest to work. We are going to use Puppet to automate updating and deploying MS Office 2019. For the “updating” I have a manifest that calls a PowerShell script. This manifest runs on our update server. If I run the Puppet Agent manually the manifest works and calls the PowerShell script and completes as desired, BUT if I let the Puppet Agent run on it own it will not execute the PowerShell script. Amplifying information provided in the example script that I am using below. The fact that what I have works when I run the Puppet Agent manually tells me it should work on its own, I’m just missing something. I appreciate any and all help with this, thank you.

Configuration: Update server has internet access which is needed to download the MS update. Our update files are hosted on another file server that does not have internet access but does have access to our full network. Once I have this working on its own I’ll get this one manifest to run on a schedule of once a week to go out and check for an update of MS Office 2019.

Here is the manifest I have:

This manifest checks to ensure the temp folder on the server is in place, then downloads the PowerShell script from the Puppet Master to the temp folder. The manifest then starts PowerShell and runs the script. This all works if the Puppet Agent is started and ran manually. When the Puppet Agent runs on its own it will download the PowerShell script from the Puppet Master but it does not start PowerShell and run the script. What am I missing? (PowerShell script is listed below.)

```
class configs::office2019download {
 file {'C:/temp':
   ensure => 'directory',
   path  => 'C:/temp',
 }
 file { 'C:/temp/off2019dl.ps1':
   ensure => 'present',
   path  => 'C:/temp/off2019dl.ps1',
   source => 'puppet:///modules/configs/deploy_apps/off2019dl.ps1',
 }
 exec { 'off2019dl':
   path   => 'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0',
   command => 'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -File "C:/temp/off2019dl.ps1"',
   timeout => 0
 }
}
```

Here is the PowerShell script:

The script starts by ensuring it can run without any user input and then executes the command that downloads the MS Office 2019 update from Microsoft.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Start-Process -filepath "\\Remote\server\file\path\setup.exe" -argumentlist "/download \\Remote\server\file\path\Configuration.xml"
```

Comment: Your user account might have permission to browse `"\\Remote\server\file\path\setup.exe"`, but does the account that's running the puppet agent service on the machine have permission to access it?

Comment: Thank you Mathias R. Jessen. I didn't think about the account permissions. Going to relook at all that.